# pod spec lint validation fail : Unable to find matching .xcframework slice for the current build architectures (x86_64 i386)

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec, xcframework

I already have my framework in cocoapod, using xcframework with several framework inside :
ios-arm64
ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst
ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator
tvos-arm64
tvos-arm64_x86_64-simulator

On my first push, I only put s.ios.deployment_target but forget s.tvos.deployment_target in my podspec. I edit the podspec file (updated s.version old was 1.0.0, new is 1.0.0-tvOS , adding s.tvos.deployment_target), commit and push on github, and create a tag with the same name as the version.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name             = 'projectSwift'
s.version          = '1.0.0-tvOS'
s.summary          = 'summ'
s.description      = 'descri'
s.homepage         = 'http://homepage.com'
s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
s.author           = { 'author' => 'author@mmmail.com' }
s.source           = { :git => 'linktogit', :tag => s.version  }
s.vendored_frameworks = "projectSwift.xcframework"
s.ios.deployment_target = '10.2'
s.tvos.deployment_target = '9.0'
s.user_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
end
```

When I try after to pod spec lint, it fail with this error :

```
pod spec lint --no-clean

Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1

 -> projectSwift (1.0.0-tvOS)
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Building targets in parallel
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using codesigning identity override: -
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file and one is not being generated automatically. (in target 'App' from project 'App')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in 'projectSwift/projectSwift.xcframework projectSwift framework ios-arm64 ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator' for the current build architectures (x86_64 i386).
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/adminlocal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bmhifwqmbbcfjnftngtmnjgbwkek/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/projectSwift'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Pods workspace available at `/var/folders/_b/5v6y69j55cs0c_3fcw0cf5m80000gp/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20210316-13156-1ipai8f-projectSwift/App.xcworkspace` for inspection.

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error.
```

I didn't modify anything else than the podspec.